# for loop in iPhone

Tags: iphone, loops, for-loop

```
nodes = [doc nodesForXPath:@"//user" error: nil];
            for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
                [itemPreDict setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue] forKey:@"name"];
                [itemPreDict setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"gender"] stringValue] forKey:@"gender"];
                [itemPreDict setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"dob"] stringValue] forKey:@"dob"];

                [itemDict setObject:itemPreDict forKey:[[node attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue]];

            }
```

In the end of loop, I'm getting 10 dicts (10 users) with same info for last user in a list, how can I get 10 dicts with different user info. Help Me Please!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are rewriting the same `itemPreDict` over and over again. To store different info, you need to create 10 different dictionaries. Try

```
        for (CXMLElement *node in nodes) {
            NSMutableDictionary* itemPreDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            // ^----------
            [itemPreDict setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue] forKey:@"name"];
            [itemPreDict setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"gender"] stringValue] forKey:@"gender"];
            [itemPreDict setObject:[[node attributeForName:@"dob"] stringValue] forKey:@"dob"];

            [itemDict setObject:itemPreDict forKey:[[node attributeForName:@"name"] stringValue]];
            // v----------
            [itemPreDict release];
        }
```

instead.

(Since you need to create a dictionary anyway, use `-initWithObjectsAndKeys:` instead of calling `-setObject:` three times. This also allows `itemPreDict` to be an NSDictionary instead of NSMutableDictionary.)